# Error Loading > module.exports = require("three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader") in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, three.js, next.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using `react-three-fiber`,`three` and `nextjs` to display some birds which is a common example in `threejs`! Here is my index file of a `nextjs` app:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Canvas, useFrame, useLoader } from 'react-three-fiber';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

function Box(props) {
  // This reference will give us direct access to the mesh
  const mesh = useRef();

  // Set up state for the hovered and active state
  const [hovered, setHover] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  // Rotate mesh every frame, this is outside of React without overhead
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign,no-multi-assign
  useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01));

  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      scale={active ? [1.5, 1.5, 1.5] : [1, 1, 1]}
      onClick={e => setActive(!active)}
      onPointerOver={e => setHover(true)}
      onPointerOut={e => setHover(false)}
    >
      <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial
        attach="material"
        color={hovered ? 'hotpink' : 'orange'}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
}

// This component was auto-generated from GLTF by: https://github.com/react-spring/gltfjsx
function Bird({ speed, factor, url, ...props }) {
  const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, url);
  const group = useRef();
  const [mixer] = useState(() => new THREE.AnimationMixer());
  useEffect(
    () => void mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0], group.current).play(),
    [gltf.animations, mixer],
  );
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    group.current.rotation.y +=
      Math.sin((delta * factor) / 2) * Math.cos((delta * factor) / 2) * 1.5;
    mixer.update(delta * speed);
  });
  return (
    <group ref={group}>
      <scene name="Scene" {...props}>
        <mesh
          name="Object_0"
          morphTargetDictionary={gltf.__$[1].morphTargetDictionary}
          morphTargetInfluences={gltf.__$[1].morphTargetInfluences}
          rotation={[1.5707964611537577, 0, 0]}
        >
          <bufferGeometry attach="geometry" {...gltf.__$[1].geometry} />
          <meshStandardMaterial
            attach="material"
            {...gltf.__$[1].material}
            name="Material_0_COLOR_0"
          />
        </mesh>
      </scene>
    </group>
  );
}

function Birds() {
  return new Array(2).fill().map((_, i) => {
    const x = (15 + Math.random() * 30) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? -1 : 1);
    const y = -10 + Math.random() * 20;
    const z = -5 + Math.random() * 10;
    const bird = ['stork', 'parrot', 'flamingo'][Math.round(Math.random() * 2)];
    const speed = bird === 'stork' ? 0.5 : bird === 'flamingo' ? 2 : 5;
    const factor =
      bird === 'stork'
        ? 0.5 + Math.random()
        : bird === 'flamingo'
        ? 0.25 + Math.random()
        : 1 + Math.random() - 0.5;
    return (
      <Bird
        key={i}
        position={[x, y, z]}
        rotation={[0, x > 0 ? Math.PI : 0, 0]}
        speed={speed}
        factor={factor}
        url={`/static/glb/${bird}.glb`}
      />
    );
  });
}

const MyComponent = props => {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight />
      <pointLight position={[10, 0, 10]} />
      <Box position={[-1.2, 2, 0]} />
      <Box position={[1.2, 0, 0]} />
      <Box position={[3, -2, 0]} />
      <Birds />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

My files are in `static/glb/...` folder! The problem is with the **GLTFLoader** loader. I tries **extend** method of `"react-three-fiber"` but not helpful!

I think maybe it's because of **SSR**. Do you think so?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm about 3 months late, but I hope this will solve any doubts in case anyone finds this question.

First of all you will need to import the GLB render, your app doesn't currently know which GLB file you're trying to render.
Something like this should do:

```js
import MyCustomRender from 'src/static/glb/an_awesome_bird.glb'
```

Then, each time you instantiate the bird component, you will be able to pass it as a prop, as in

```js
<Bird
    key={i}
    position={[x, y, z]}
    rotation={[0, x > 0 ? Math.PI : 0, 0]}
    speed={speed}
    factor={factor}
    url={MyCustomRender}
/>
```

Now, since you're using NextJS, that means you're currently using WebPack to bundle your application.

The thing is, WebPack doesn't know right from the start what a `glb` or `GLTF` file is, you have to let this little module know how to behave when importing a file with said extension.

You can do that by updating the `next.config.js` file like this:

```
module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
  webpack (config, options) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(glb|gltf)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
      }
    })
    return config
  }
}))
```

This essentially means you're telling Webpack "Hey, if you see me importing any .gltf or .glb files, it means I want their path, so give me their URL".

In case you don't have the file-loader for Webpack installed, you can always do

```sh
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

A few days ago I made this repo using the exact same stack:

https://github.com/franco-roura/react-game

(Except I didn't use NextJS, so my `next.config.js` is actually `webpack.config.js`)

Hope it helps you clearing any doubts!

Comment: Thank you I have to test your solutions to see how it helps but I figured it out in another way. I will post my solution here as well I almost forgot to do that!

Comment: Glad I could help 